# Sanitize/validate input in ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, sanitization

Per [this](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet-and-what-to-do-instead#validation) page, in ASP.NET 5, you cannot depend on request validation, which I believe was a feature of IIS/ASP.NET. Since ASP.NET 5 can be self-hosted with linux support, we must do it our selves. Sounds good.

The question is, what is the recommend way to do it for ASP.NET 5? Is there a built in MVC 6 attribute that will sanitize/validate? What exactly did the old way detect? Script tags? Style tags?

Comment: Regarding the article no difference for asp.net 5. Just use viewmodels with display annotations for the properties.

Comment: Before asp.net 5, the request framework itself (httpmodules/handlers) had request validation built in. You could disable it via the web.config, but it was a feature of the handlers in the GAC, used in IIS. I am aware of how to do this myself using model attributes, but so far, there is no official way to do this from Microsoft, and their should be. Perhaps a middleware that intercepts posted form values for site-wide usage by default? Idk. This is very important in web development, and an answer should be provided by Microsoft on how we *should* do it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend FluentValidation for ASP.NET 5:

```
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person> {
    public PersonValidator() {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).Length(0, 10);
        RuleFor(x => x.Email).EmailAddress();
        RuleFor(x => x.Age).InclusiveBetween(18, 60);
    }
}
```

https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet#asp-net-mvc-5